# How to invoke (Serverless) and display in my terminal a output from a AWS-Lambda trigged by AWS-IoT topic (Production)?

Tags: lambda, invoke, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda function whose the event is an AWS-IoT topic. Some time ago I used to use a command to invoke (using serverless) a function in production trough my terminal and when that function was trigged by the event I saw the output in my terminal. I dont remeber exactly the command. In fact I dont want to run the function by `sls invoke -f myFunction`. I want to listen that function when it is trigged. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command `sls logs -f hello -t`